# C# Send Push Notification Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send a notification to Firebase Messaging according to the https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet package.

I generated a private key in Firebase and added the project.
To send I am doing it as follows.

```
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<dynamic> PostMensagem()
        {
            
            var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
            {
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    ["FirstName"] = "FirstName",
                    ["LastName"] = "LastName"
                },
                Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification
                {
                    Title = "Message Title",
                    Body = "Message Body"
                },
                Android = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.AndroidConfig()
                {
                    Priority = Priority.Normal,
                    TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                    RestrictedPackageName = "com.example.test",
                },
                Topic = "Topic",
            };

            var result = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine(result); //projects/myapp/messages/2492588335721724324
           
            return result;
        }
```

In response, I receive a url something like "//projects/myapp/messages/2492588335721724324" but the notification does not reach the cloud and neither does android.

Am I forgetting something? What do I need to do to get notifications sent from my SDK project to appear in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

[image: Firebase Cloud Messaging]

Comment: Do you have android application capable of receiving message?

Comment: Yes I have. When I create a notification through the Firebase website it appears on android. It just doesn't appear on android and on the website when sending C#.

Comment: You need to include firebase configuration file in your mvc project -> projectname.firebase.json Did you do that? If so make sure build action is set to content.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Note that the message appears to be sent successfully. I get it in the end. 
"/projects/myapp/messages /492588335721724324"

I honestly am not seeing what is wrong.

Comment: Is the device subscribed to your topic?

Comment: Device must be subscribed to topic or you send message to individual device id.

Comment: What a shame. It was missing to subscribe to the topic itself. Thank you Hiranda. Although the notification still does not appear on the firebase website, however it is now received on Android. Thank you very much for your personal help.