# how to send firebase push notifcation to ios app

Tags: c#, ios, .net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to use firebase to send push notification to ios ,
I implement the frontend part and retrieve the device token correctly..
when I try to send notification from Firebase console recceived the notification successffully on ios app.
I tried sending the from my Dotnet core C# APi but not received the notification on ios.
ANy one please share how to send push notification from C# code to ios using firebase.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Install FirebaseAdmin from https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAdmin/
more details here [C# Send Push Notification Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64874761/c-sharp-send-push-notification-firebase-cloud-messaging)
the notification content

```
            FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification();

            notification.Body = Message;
            notification.ImageUrl = ImageUrl ;
            notification.Title = Title ;
            
            FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.AndroidNotification androidNotification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.AndroidNotification();
            
            androidNotification.Body = Message;
            androidNotification.Color = "#2D82FF";
            androidNotification.ImageUrl = ImageUrl ;
            androidNotification.Title = Title ;
            androidNotification.ChannelId = "12";
            androidNotification.Icon = "Icon" ;
            androidNotification.Sound = "default";
            FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.AndroidConfig androidConfig = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.AndroidConfig();
            androidConfig.CollapseKey = CollapseKey Id;
            androidConfig.Priority = FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Priority.High;
            androidConfig.Notification = androidNotification;
            androidConfig.TimeToLive = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
             var msg = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message();



            msg.Notification = notification;
            msg.Android = androidConfig;
            msg.Token = LastDeviceFCMToken;
            try
            {
             await FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(msg);
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
```

with this declaration of notification, anyway will be your target Android or Ios will revice the notification

Comment: I am looking for ios..does this work on ios..?

Comment: yes it will send the notification Android / Ios depend on the token

Comment: text me back if there's any problem :)

Comment: Any other way then this..?

Comment: all the ways using https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAdmin/

Comment: I am getting this in result 
AsyncState  : null
id : 25
Status : WaitingforActivation
Exception : Null


Any Idea..what it mean..?